# Usando Java junto com C

Tags: java, c, interoperabilidade, jni

Estou trabalhando num projeto de micro controlador. Meu fonte está todo em C entretanto gostaria de interagir com esse programa utilizando Java. Isto seria possível? Por exemplo: O programa em C executa comandos de controle do microcontrolador e por uma interface gráfica em Java gostaria de enviar os comandos para o programa em C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se você quer apenas fazer a comunicação entre dois programas, não há grande dificuldade se o dispositivo prover recursos para tal. Programas se comunicam o tempo todo e não importam em que linguagens eles estejam.

Mesmo que desejasse que código em Java se comunicasse como código em C no mesmo programa ainda seria possível através de [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). Se a comunicação for muito difícil integrar o código em C ao Java pode ser uma alternativa. Mas já aviso que não é tarefa das mais fáceis.

Precisaria analisar se o controlador tem alguma forma de processos se comunicarem de forma eficiente. Eventualmente, em casos extremos seja necessário utilizar algum código em C junto ao Java para criar esta forma de comunicação provavelmente acessando memória de forma compartilhada (há diversas implicações nisto se o sistema operacional não ajuda).

Também poderia usar o protocolo TCP para fazer a comunicação desde que ambos estejam aptos para fazer esta comunicação. Isto depende de bibliotecas apropriadas nos dois programas ou código especializado.

Além disto é possível usar a troca de informações por arquivos se o controlador utiliza alguma forma de armazenamento.

Teria que analisar a documentação do controlador e/ou sistema operacional que roda nele além de verificar as bibliotecas disponíveis para ele nas duas linguagens. Mas se nada disto for possível, é melhor desistir de fazer isto no controlador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vlw bigown. Vou dar uma pesquisada em JNI derrepente pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, verifique se o seu microcontrolador permite comunicação serial (USART) e simplesmente implemente a comunicação usando Java.

Existe uma classe muito boa que pode te auxiliar nesse processo chamada [RXTX](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-a-api-rxtx-para-manipulacao-da-serial-parte-i/6722).

Essa é apenas uma das formas de se comunicar entre sistemas embarcados e demais dispositivos como um PC, por exemplo. Entretanto, de fácil implementação e amplo uso no mercado.